# Writing a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

Im doing my first plugin in jquery for practising and It won't work, i have seen tutorials and the api documentation and didnt find the problem.

I have a select in html and a span.sl1. and I call it this way:

```
$("select").selectFunc("onChange");
```

My plugin code is:

```
    (function( $ ){
var metodos = {
    init : function(opciones) {   
        var configuracion = {  
            container:$('span.sl1'),
            valor:$(this).val()
        };  
        return this.each(function(){  
            if(opciones){  
                configuracion = $.extend(configuracion,opciones);  
            }  
        });  
    },
    onChange:function(opciones){
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).bind('change',function(){
                container.html(valor);
            });
        });
    },
    unbind : function (){  
        return this.each(function(){  
            $(this).unbind('mouseover');  
            $(this).unbind('mouseout');  
        });  
    }  
};
$.fn.selectFunc = function( metodos ) {
    if (metodos[method] ) {
        return metodos[ metodo ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( argumentos, 1 ));
    }
    else if ( typeof metodo === 'object' || ! metodo ) {
        return metodos.init.apply( this, argumentos );
    }
    else {
        $.error( 'Este método ' +  metodo + ' no existe en jQuery.estiloPropio' );
    }    
};
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: you are passing in `metodos`, which should be `method` or `metodo`, and then you are using `method` in some places and `metodo` in others. You also changed `arguments` to `argumentos`. Just a theory, but did you have your browser translate the page where you saw that code?

Comment: @MrOBrian I didn't use the translator, I just forget to change that... The reason I write it in spanish is because my boss, who asked me to do a jquery plugin want all code in spanish cos my mates dont speak english... Anyway, I chanded now all well, but it still wont work

Comment: I see. Well, once you fix up the variable naming, and pass in the correct variable to your function, it should work.

Comment: Another thing that shouldn't be translated: `jQuery.estiloPropio`

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to check [this page](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/) for a quick jquery plugin boilerplate.